# Existence of holomorphic function under conditions

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

I have to answer this question:

Is there a holomorphic function $f:\Omega =\{z\in \mathbb{C} \mid |z|<2\} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that

1. For all  $n \in \mathbb{N}\backslash\{0\}: f\left(\frac1n\right)=e^{-n}$
2. For all  $n \in \mathbb{N}\backslash\{0\}: f\left(\frac1n\right)=\sin(\frac{\pi n}{2})$

---

My first try:

1. If $f(z):= e^{-\frac1z} \, \Rightarrow \forall \ n:  f\left(\frac1n\right) = e^{-\frac{1}{1/n}} = e^{-n}$ but $f$ has an essential singularity at $z=0$ hence is not holomorphic in $\Omega$
2. If $f(z):= \sin \frac{\pi}{2z} \, \Rightarrow \forall \ n:  f\left(\frac1n\right) = \sin \frac{\pi}{2\frac{1}{n}} = \sin \frac{\pi n}{2}$ but $f$ has an essential singularity at $z=0$ hence is not holomorphic in $\Omega$

---

My second try:

$f(z):= \sum_{l=0}^{\infty} a_l z^l$

1. The condition is 
   $f\left(\frac1n\right)= \sum_{l=0}^{\infty} a_l \left(\frac1n\right)^l \overset{!}{=} \sum_{l=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-n)^l}{l!} = e^{-n}$ which gives my the following: $$f(z) = \sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^l z^{-l}}{l!}$$
   Such a function has an essential singularity in 0 hence is not holomorphic in $\Omega$
2. The condition is 
   $$f\left(\frac1n\right)= \sum_{l=0}^{\infty} a_l \left(\frac1n\right)^l \overset{!}{=} \sum_{l=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^l\left(\frac{\pi n}{2}\right)^{2l+1}}{(2l+1)!} = \sin \frac{\pi n}{2}$$ which gives my the following: $$f(z) = \sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^l \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{2l+1}}{(2l+1)!}z^{-(2l+1)}$$
   Such a function has an essential singularity in 0 hence is not holomorphic in $\Omega$

Please check my answer because I really think I'm missing something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If such $f$ existed, then $f(0)=0$, due to continuity at $z=0$,  and hence there would be an integer $k$ (the order of the zero), such that $f(z)=z^kg(z)$, where $g$ is also analytic in $\{z:|z|<2\}$, and $g(0)\ne 0$. But
   $$
   \mathrm{e}^{-n}=f\big(\tfrac{1}{n}\big)=\left(\tfrac{1}{n}\right)^kg\big(\tfrac{1}{n}\big),
   $$ 
   and hence
   $$
   g\big(\tfrac{1}{n}\big)=n^k\mathrm{e}^{-n}.
   $$
   But 
   $$
   g(0)=\lim_{n\to\infty} g\big(\tfrac{1}{n}\big)=
   \lim_{n\to\infty}n^k\mathrm{e}^{-n}=0,
   $$ 
   which is a contradiction. Hence no such $f$ exists.
2. If such $f$ existed, then the limit $f(\frac{1}{n})$, as would have existed. But, the sequence $\sin (n\pi/2)$ clearly does not have a limit.